# Delphi 2007 Debugger Gone

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Scenario:

- Delphi did a non-normal shutdown.
- When I restarted I got the messages "Could not find xxxxx.bpl - Would you like to load this next time?" (NOTE: not exact language of message; but close).  It did this on a couple files.
- Unfortunately I said "No - Don't Load on next Startup" and also did not note the specific bpl file names.  I do recall they were in the CodeGear directory.  This was stupid/lazy on my part.
- Delphi loads and compiles but there is no Debugging available (basically all the options under the **Run** menu are disabled).
- Under **Tools->Options->Debugger Options** there is no **CodeGear Debuggers**.

So basically I have totally disabled the debugging.  Anyone know how I can get it back?

Comment: did you try enabling all packages (at leat those in CG directory) from the component menu ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First check that you did not destroy critical elements in the Windows `PATH` environment variable. That will prevent core elements of the IDE from loading, even if the registry settings are correct.

Next,  try saving this as bdsfix.reg then run it by double-clicking it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\5.0\Known IDE Packages]
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\asmview100.bpl"="Assembly Browser Package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\codetemplates100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\coreproide100.bpl"="Core IDE Pro Package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\dbkdebugide100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\dbkdebugproide100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\dotnetcoreide100.bpl"=".NET Core IDE Package"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\exceptiondiag100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\fileexplorer100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\historyide100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\htmlhelp2100.bpl"="Borland HtmlHelp Viewer"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\idefilefilters100.bpl"="IDE File filters"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\plugview100.bpl"="Pluggable Tree View Package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\projecttargets100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\refactoride100.bpl"="Borland Core Refactoring Package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\startpageide100.bpl"="Borland Start Page IDE Package"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\todoide100.bpl"="Borland ToDo"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphidotnetcore100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\DataExplorer100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\htmide100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\htmltidy100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\mlcc100.bpl"="(Untitled)"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\5.0\Known IDE Packages\Delphi]
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphicompro100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphicoreproide100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphide100.bpl"="Delphi Win32 IDE Personality"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphierrorinsite100.bpl"="Delphi Error Insite Package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphipro100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\comcore100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphivclide100.bpl"="Delphi VCL Designer IDE Package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\vclmenudesigner100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\win32debugide100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\win32debugproide100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\iteidew32100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\TGIDE100.bpl"="Borland Together IDE Integration"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\unittestide100.bpl"="(Untitled)"
```

Second attempt, if the above does not work is to back up (export to .reg file from regedit) the following key and then very carefully, rename this registry key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\5.0`  (Delphi 2007 specific)

I recommend renaming it to

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\4.0`  (Makes it invisible to 2007 but easily recoverable)

For more recent delphi versions, look under  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Codegear or HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero for a `BDS` sub-folder, and then a number, XE is 8.0 or XE2 is 9.0.

This will reset your local login account's delphi settings to factory install defaults.
You can add back in the contents of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\5.0\Known Packages' to get back your additional third party packages.

**Update** The OP was actually missing the file `dbkdebugide100.bpl`

Comment: Tried the first; it successfully imported with no problems.  But still did not work.  Trying 2nd solution.

Comment: Awesome - got it.  After deleting the 5.0 registry and then restarting Delphi it popped up the message that dbkdebugide100.bpl could not be found.  Somehow it got deleted.  I got a copy from a different computer.  And did as you said to export/import Known packages and all is well.  Thank you very much - a life saver for sure!!!!

Comment: Check your library path and other settings too.