# How to install and use another debugger in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, debugging

After reading the problem with debugger in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929354/delphi-2007-debugger-gone), I am curious if there is a documented way to install third parties debuggers.

If you did not understand, take a look at Tools->Options in Debuggers Options there's a Registered Debuggers pane. How can I integrate another one that are not listed there?

Comment: There aren't any debuggers that are any better and can show source code

Comment: That doesn't mean what you think it means.  And there are no third party or external debuggers for Delphi.  But some extra tools that are not really debuggers might be registered there.  I am thinking of AQTime and tools like that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan probably not. I'm a Delphi Debugger fan too :). This, however, does not mean that I could not use another debugger in the future. IDK, weird things happens in programmers dimension. D:

Comment: @WarrenP I see that it doesn't appears to mean what I thought it would mean. I see AQTime there too, but I did not found nothing about that... And if I was a debugger developer? Maybe I worked on [Ollydbg](http://www.ollydbg.de)? But the questions that bugged me was "Why would Delphi developers put a TListboxlike control as Registered Debuggers pane if it could not be edited?" Google did not help, so... SO! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to integrate yourself any third party tool... The tool itself should integrate itself during its installation or later with an option... Usually, you have to close Delphi.

For instance, Embarcadero installs the default debuggers...
Then, AQTime, during its setup, does the same...

Then, as you've seen it, if the integration is done as expected, you can see them:
[image]

And so on... you can find other tools (check the date/version before trying one of them) on [this page.](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=1525)

**Update:**

I don't know what you should call... but you have to start with an import:
[image: Tools API]

Comment: Thanks Whiler. But, if I am a developer of such tools, how can I integrate it to Delphi IDE?

Comment: Ok. I can go on with that. I don't think I will find any examples of this specific case, so I'm accepting your answer. For future reference, thought, I'm adding links of doc about that. [ToolsAPI](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Extending_the_IDE_Index) and [Notifying a Wizard](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Notifying_a_Wizard_of_IDE_Events).

Comment: Reading about it. It seems that we can extend Delphi Debugger, but not use another one.